# Знаки вопроса в html в теге pre

Tags: html, utf-8

В теге `pre` иногда показываются знаки вопроса в ромбе.
Кодировка utf-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто сталкивался?

Comment: Это происходит с одной и той же страницей устойчиво или несколько перезагрузок одной и той же страницы дают разные результаты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это проблема возникает в случаях, когда страница разбивается на куски, чтобы отправить клиенту отдельными пакетами, причем граница куска проходит по одному из многобайтовых символов. Юникодный символ "е" состоит из двух байтов: один байт попадает в один пакет, а другой байт в другой пакет. Обычно TCP справляется с тем, чтобы собрать все пакеты в цельное сообщение без ошибок, но иногда стороннее ПО портит пакеты, из-за чего юникодные символы на границах становятся нечитаемыми. Такую проблему, например, создаёт браузерный мониторинг от [NewRelic](https://newrelic.com/).

Однозначного решения нет. В первую очередь нужно разобраться, какое именно ПО вносит изменения в пакеты. После этого, если есть доступ к этому ПО, то можно попробовать исправить ошибку. Если есть доступ к поддержке этого ПО, то обратиться туда. Либо просто отказаться от его использования. В частности в NewRelic можно отключить браузерный мониторинг, оставив только серверный.

Comment: стоит плагин pjax... https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: @ВикторВиктор, как решили проблему? Отказались от использования плагина и проблема исчезла?

Comment: Я не решил проблему. От плагина отказываться вообще не хочется, он мне нужен. Буду дальше искать решение. Если не найду — буду искать аналог плагина...