# Знаки вопроса вместо русского текста на сайте

Tags: html, reactjs, unicode

Есть шаблон сайта, а он весь на английском.
Если поставить русскую надпись, то каждая буква в надписи преобразуются в `"�"`.
Хотя в `head` стоит `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`.
Смотрел похожие вопросы тут, ничего не нашёл.

Comment: для начала разберитесь, в какой кодировке вы «поставили русскую надпись».

Comment: Вот тут дали хороший комментарий [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589678/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-html-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b5-pre?rq=1)

Comment: Я писал в Vusial Studio, а кодировку теперь буду менять в ручную в Notepad++.
Я честно не знаю, как изменить параметр сохранения файла в VS